# Basic Pseudocode for using SVD with Movielens/Netflix type data set

Tags: recommendation-engine, prediction, netflix, collaborative-filtering, svd

I'm struggling to figure out how exactly to begin using SVD with a MovieLens/Netflix type data set for rating predictions. I'd very much appreciate any simple samples in python/java, or basic pseudocode of the process involved. There are a number of papers/posts that summarise the overall concept but I'm not sure how to begin implementing it, even using a number of the suggested libraries.

As far as I understand, I need to convert my initial data set as follows:

Initial data set:

```
    user    movie   rating
    1       43      3
    1       57      2
    2       219     4
```

Need to pivot to be:

```
user        1   2
movie   43  3   0
        57  2   0
        219 0   4
```

At this point, do I simply need to inject this Matrix into an SVD algorithm as provided by available libraries, and then (somehow) extract results, or is there more work required on my part?

Some information I've read:

http://www.netflixprize.com/community/viewtopic.php?id=1043 
http://sifter.org/~simon/journal/20061211.html 
http://www.slideshare.net/NYCPredictiveAnalytics/building-a-recommendation-engine-an-example-of-a-product-recommendation-engine 
http://www.slideshare.net/bmabey/svd-and-the-netflix-dataset-presentation 
.. and a number of other papers

Some libraries:
[LingPipe(java)](http://alias-i.com/lingpipe/demos/tutorial/svd/read-me.html)
[Jama(java)](http://math.nist.gov/javanumerics/jama/)  
[Pyrsvd(python)](http://code.google.com/p/pyrsvd/)

Any tips at all would be appreciated, especially on a basic data set.
Thanks very much,
Oli

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See [SVDRecommender](http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/mahout/trunk/core/src/main/java/org/apache/mahout/cf/taste/impl/recommender/svd/SVDRecommender.java) in Apache Mahout. Your question about input format entirely depends on what library or code you're using. There's not one standard. At some level, yes, the code will construct some kind of matrix internally. For Mahout, the input for all recommenders, when supplied as a file, is a CSV file with rows like `userID,itemID,rating`.

Comment: Thanks Sean, that looks really great. I'm going to try it out today.

Answer (score 2):

**Data set:** http://www.grouplens.org/node/73

**SVD:** why not just do it in `SAGE` if you don't understand how to do SVD? Wolfram alpha or http://www.bluebit.gr/matrix-calculator/ will decompose the matrix for you, or it's on Wikipedia.

Comment: Hi Lao, really appreciate you getting back to me. I should have clarified that I've used the data set and have done some standard kNN prediction using Pearson/cosine for similarity, with a subset of the Movielens data set. Given what I've read SVD should give me better results here, so I was keen to actually implement it myself, but am not sure of the steps I need to take given the Movielens data set. As you suggested, I'm going to play with SAGE to see can I figure out the process beginning to end; if you had any rough guidelines about the steps to take, I'd appreciate it. Thanks, oli.

Comment: Sure, watch this lecture: http://video.google.com/videoplay?docid=-3184505661983090095#. You split the matrix into three matrices. It's like an eigendecomposition.